# google maps V3 : in javascript api, render route obtained with web api

Tags: google-maps, direction

I have to obtain route directions with the Google maps v3 WEB (http request) api (computations are made server-side, based on this data, without client interaction, so no JS available). Then, the routes are sorted out with internal logic, and the server (apache/PHP) send a web html/js/jQuery page to the client, which displays a page with a Google map (displayed with JS (ajax) api)

On this map, i would like to render the routes obtained earlier by the server with the web api.

So I tried to give the DirectionsResult to the google.maps.DirectionsRenderer::setDirections() but it does nothing, and firebug doesn't trace any error (and google JS if obfuscated, of course)

Yes, I first set the map with setMap(), and the directionsRenderer is initialized correctly, all that is OK !

It seems that de DirectionsResult is not the same when obtained from Web API and from JS API.

Is there a way to "translate" it, so that it could be rendered ?

The alternative would be to do the route computations again on the client side with the ajax api, only to render them, but I think this is stupid to recompute directions as I already have them; so I don't want to do it this way unless it is the only way.

Answer (score 5):

You need to typecast each Object on the JSON response to the proper kind.

The web service API also doesn't return the `ub` property of the [DirectionsResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsResult) (undocumented property), you need that as well. The `DirectionsRenderer` expects `ub.travelMode`, `ub.origin` and `ub.destination` (all strings). The `origin` and `destination` are only used if you enable the `draggable` property on the [DirectionsRendererOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions) - they are basically the same value that you pass on the `DirectionsService#route()` call.

Assuming you are on a browser that supports the ES5 `Array#forEach` method:

```
function typecastRoutes(routes){
    routes.forEach(function(route){
        route.bounds = asBounds(route.bounds);
        // I don't think `overview_path` is used but it exists on the
        // response of DirectionsService.route()
        route.overview_path = asPath(route.overview_polyline);

        route.legs.forEach(function(leg){
            leg.start_location = asLatLng(leg.start_location);
            leg.end_location   = asLatLng(leg.end_location);

            leg.steps.forEach(function(step){
                step.start_location = asLatLng(step.start_location);
                step.end_location   = asLatLng(step.end_location);
                step.path = asPath(step.polyline);
            });

        });
    });
}

function asBounds(boundsObject){
    return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(asLatLng(boundsObject.southwest),
                                    asLatLng(boundsObject.northeast));
}

function asLatLng(latLngObject){
    return new google.maps.LatLng(latLngObject.lat, latLngObject.lng);
}

function asPath(encodedPolyObject){
    return google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath( encodedPolyObject.points );
}
```

So you would use it like this:

```
var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

function renderDirections(map, response, request){
    renderer.setOptions({
        directions : {
            routes : typecastRoutes(response.routes),
            // "ub" is important and not returned by web service it's an
            // object containing "origin", "destination" and "travelMode"
            ub : request
        },
        draggable : true,
        map : map
    });
}
```

PS: make sure you load the [Geometry Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) otherwise the `google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath` method won't be available.

Answer (score 2):

@MillerMedeiros's answer is excellent and saved me hours of work.  I did have to make one change to the code to get it to work for the V3 of the Maps API.

Instead of:

```
ub: request
```

It should be:

```
request:request
```

I was getting "travelMode not defined" errors and I had it defined in the request variable.  When I went through the google code I found that ub had been replaced by request in V3.

Now I'm able to render data received from the google maps web service to the map using the JavaScript API.